# ajax product detail popup shows header footer

Tags: magento

i just installed theme but when i click product detail ajax pop up it shows header and footer , is there any setting in admin to add or remove that:

link of website :http://bellb2b.com/

link of qucik view ajax url :
http://bellb2b.com/ajax/index/options/product_id/19/

i changes theme to default one still same bug

how can i solve bug please guide